# no output for php session code being generated

Tags: session, session-variables

I am having a problem regarding PHP sessions. this code is expected to display thank you for registering and the corresponding username and email id but it is not displaying anything! please help me out!

```
<?php
//initialize session data
session_start();
if(isset($_SERVER['username'])){
    echo "you are already logged in as: ".$_SERVER['username'];
}
elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD' == 'POST']){
    if(!empty(trim($_POST['username'])) && !empty(trim($_POST['email']))){
        $uname = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        echo "thanks for registering <br/>";
        echo "your username: $uname <br/>";
        echo "your email: $email <br/>";
    }
    else{
        echo "please fill both the fields properly";
    }
}
else{ ?>
<form action="index.html?username=overwritten" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username here.." name="username"><br/>
    <input type="email" placeholder="email here.." name="email"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
<?php } 
?>
```

It is also displaying:
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/samiary.com/index.php on line 7
on the top
please help me out, I am just a beginner.

Comment: I suppose instead of `$_SERVER['username']` you need `$_SESSION['username']`

Answer (score 0):

You have error near `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`. Try this:

```
<?php
//initialize session data
session_start();
if(isset($_SERVER['username'])){
    echo "you are already logged in as: ".$_SERVER['username'];
}
elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    if(!empty(trim($_POST['username'])) && !empty(trim($_POST['email']))){
        $uname = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        echo "thanks for registering <br/>";
        echo "your username: $uname <br/>";
        echo "your email: $email <br/>";
    }
    else{
        echo "please fill both the fields properly";
    }
}
else{ ?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username here.." name="username"><br/>
    <input type="email" placeholder="email here.." name="email"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
<?php } 
?>
```